# Sort search/find Nautilus results in Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 17.04

In Ubuntu 17.04, it seems that when searching you cannot click on the column headers to sort results Name/Size/Modified/etc.

This really makes what used to be an easy operation essentially impossible.

Is this possible in 17.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ubuntu Zesty sorting is done from the search bar:

[image]

For sorting from the columns that appeasrs not to be the default settings anymore.

Comment: Thanks. This allows specification of a date criteria but not sorting of results. Correct?

Comment: Yes it appears that ability was removed.

Comment: For info, I've reported this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1698351).